# bootstrap issue with col class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

hi all i'm trying to code a website and i have issue with col class what ever i use it takes all my screen width col-md-4 or col-md-6 or col-md-3 i don't know if the problem from my screen resolution wich is 1024 × 768 or what here's the thing

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
       <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">RTWM.Com</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    
    </ul>
   </div>
  </nav>
  <header>
  
   <div class="text-center">
   
    <h1>RTWM FOR UNIFORMS</h1>
    <h3>Proud To Serve You</h3>
   </div>
  
  </header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  
   <div class="col-md-12">
   
    <div class="col-md-6">
     At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
    </div>
   
   </div>
  
  </div>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

i'm still learning and newbie

Answer (score 1):

Actually your code working as is, if I just add `bootstrap.css` to id from [CDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/). Is `css/bootstrap.css` file really exists in your local folder?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
       <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
  <header>
  
   <div class="text-center">
   
    <h1>RTWM FOR UNIFORMS</h1>
    <h3>Proud To Serve You</h3>
   </div>
  
  </header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  
   <div class="col-md-12">
   
    <div class="col-md-6">
     At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
    </div>
   
   </div>
  
  </div>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

(make sure you clicked the `Full page` link because `.col-md-*` classes only work when page width is more than 992px)

Also note, that by bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to the grid system:

> - Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.
> - Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.
> - Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

So you should always place column classes only as direct childs of `.row`.

So, the fixed code would be this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
       <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
  <header>
  
   <div class="text-center">
   
    <h1>RTWM FOR UNIFORMS</h1>
    <h3>Proud To Serve You</h3>
   </div>
  
  </header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
   
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
    </div>
    </div>
   
   </div>
   </div>
  
  </div>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: ya file is exist on my local folder but i'll try the CDN and i'll also try the row problem is my instructor wasn't using row class and i was just following him it worked good with him but didn't work with me i'll try and tell you what happened thx for your help

Comment: i did try using .row as parent of columns class but when .row was parent for 3 col-md-4 and the 3 childs went down each other each on separated line i'm really confused there must be something with my pc

Comment: Did you try to click `Run code snippet` button from code snippet in my answer and then `Full page` button? It is work as you expected? If yes, but the same code is not working on your PC when you load it from your hard drive, then I almost sure the bootstrap's CSS file is just not loaded on your page. Check the paths in your link tag etc.

Comment: idid try Run code Snippet and then full page and it's showing on full width and even tried CDN bootstrap but still have full width do you think it's from my pc ? because i think so :(

Comment: Try the `col-xs-*` classes instead of `col-md-*` then, to make sure it's not your monitor resolution. The `col-xs-6` should work if your screen width is more then 750px.

Comment: i did solved the problem and yea it was an issue from my monitor resolution on windows 10 when i switched to windows 7 and just open the index file it came so clear and fixed i have even deleted the row class code and still working without any issue thank you for your help really

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
       <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">RTWM.Com</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    
    </ul>
   </div>
  </nav>
  <header>
  
   <div class="text-center">
   
    <h1>RTWM FOR UNIFORMS</h1>
    <h3>Proud To Serve You</h3>
   </div>
  
  </header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  
   <div class="row">
   
    <div class="col-md-6">
     At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
    </div>
   
   </div>
  
  </div>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: You should change this <div class="col-md-12"> to this <div class="row"> and then add another col-md-6 or (2) col-md-3. I sure hope this helped you.

Comment: i did try your code but still have the same problem even i added another col-md-6 but it came in the next line the only class wich worked well with me even without row is col-ms i don't know what's the wrong with col-md